# C# Winforms WebBrowser POST and open RESPONSE

Tags: c#

I would like to know if it is possible to send a POST request to a specific address and after obtaining the page open this result in WebBrowser.

In my case I would like to send a date range via POST, for this I already have a php page ready, when sending the date range the page will perform a select on the database and set up a Google Chart with the result, then I would like to show this result which is the page with the graphic drawn inside the WebBrowser. The difficulty is in displaying the result in WebBrowser.

I have this C # code to send the POST request but I don't know how to open the result after POST in a WebBrowser.

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
        { "var1", "2018-01-01" }
        { "var2", "2020-04-01 23:59:59" }
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost/PostCSharp.php", content);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I appreciate all help.

[EDIT]

Following @Roman Marusyk everything worked using webBrowser1.DocumentText = responseString.

Sorry for the low level of knowledge I have.

Comment: What is "the result after POST"? Where is your `WebBrowser`? What have you tried so far?

Comment: result after POST:  it would be the complete page with the drawn chart. I wanted to send the POST and using the Navigate method to display the page processed in WebBrowser.

Comment: did you try `webBrowser1.DocumentText = responseString` ?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk I thank you infinitely, I really hadn't tried it, and it worked perfectly, thanks again !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = responseString
```